# can I hide the Acer Empowering Technology toolbar?

Tags: windows, desktop, toolbar, windows-vista

I'd like to have a very clean desktop, anyone knows if it's possible to hide the Acer Empowering Technology toolbar in the desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clicking on your start menu and typing **msconfig** in to the search box on your start menu followed by the enter key.  Once msconfig has loaded, click the tab that says startup and look for the Acer toolbar entry.  Untick that entry and then restart your machine.

Answer (score 1):

You could uninstall all of those Acer Empowering Technology programs. I always do after restoring my Acer to factory defaults.